# SetTextColour doesn't work while SetBackgroundColour works

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a grid in `Wxpython`, I'm itarating over the rows and I want that rows who are qualified for the condition to be colored in RED.

When I'm doing:

```
attr = gridlib.GridCellAttr()
attr.SetBackgroundColour('#FF0000')
grid.SetRowAttr(i, attr)
```

it works and the row gets a red background... but if I do:

```
attr = gridlib.GridCellAttr()
attr.SetTextColour('#FF0000')
grid.SetRowAttr(i, attr)
```

it doesn't work. nothing happen.

`i` is the row index.

I want the text to be red not the background.

Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The following minimal example works for me to set the colour of text in a row to red,

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="Grid")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.grid = gridlib.Grid(panel)
        self.grid.CreateGrid(3, 3)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.grid, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def set_row_colour(self, row):
        attr = gridlib.GridCellAttr()
        attr.SetTextColour('#FF0000')
        self.grid.SetRowAttr(row, attr)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    form = MyForm()
    form.set_row_colour(2)
    frame = form.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

If it isn't working for you, may be a difference in wx (I'm using 2.8.12.1)?

Comment: This one works... but I don't see what is the diffrence between this code and mine

Comment: Hmm, not sure. Maybe a bug in row choice `i`? Are you importing wx or wxPython (not sure if there is a difference)... Could be a conflict with something else (e.g. a global property setting the text colour back to black)?

Comment: `i` is simply a number, it iterates from 0 to the maximum number of rows I have in the grid. `i` is working properly I see it in the prints to console. The thing is that `SetBackgroundColour` is working perfectly... but `SetTextColour` isn't